# Showing Lebesgue Integral inequalities

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f,g: [0,1] \longrightarrow (0,\infty)$ be measurable and $\beta >0$. Assume that $$\int_{0}^{1}g(x)dx = 1.$$ Show that $$1\leq \Bigg(\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^{-\beta}g(x)dx\Bigg)\Bigg( \int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx\Bigg)^{{\beta}}.$$ My attempt: Consider the measure $\mu$ defined by $$\mu(E)=\int_Eg(x)dx,$$ whenever $E$ is lebesgue measurable subset of $[0,1].$ From here im  stuck, i think Jensen's inequality is useful here but i dont know how should apply it. 

 

 Any help and hints would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

$h(t)=t^{-\beta}$ is a convex function on $(0,\infty)$ because its second derivative is positive. Hence $h(\int f d\mu) \leq \int h(f)d\mu$ This gives the desired inequality.

Comment: Hello Dr.Murthy i didn't get the part "second derivative" also, why is it $h(t)$ not $g(t)$. Can you please enlighten me.

Comment: $h'(t)=-\beta t^{-\beta-1}$ and $h''(t)=(-\beta)(-\beta -1) t^{-\beta-1} >0$ so $h$ is convex. By Jensen's inequality $h(\int f d\mu) \leq \int h(f) d\mu$. This gives $h(\int f  (x)g(x)dx) \leq \int h(f(x)) g(x)dx$. Now use definition of $h$.

Comment: Thank you very much Dr. Murthy!!